# Symfony2 - How to access a node in a XML document being sent to a REST API with a POST request?

Tags: xml, rest, symfony, request

I can access the XML document sent to my REST API with a POST request like this:

```
$xml = $this->get('request')->getContent();
```

Given I receive the following XML document:

```
<text>
     <headline>This is the headline</headline>
     <content>some boring content bla</content>
</text>
```

How can i access the `<headline>` node?

Comment: Please stop editing back. Anyone can understand the question in a few seconds in it's current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use symfony's **[DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)** to find the content of a certain node in the received XML document.

The `filterXpath()` method accepts a simple CSS-selector style syntax.

**example:**

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$xml     = $this->get('request')->getContent();
$crawler = new Crawler($xml);

$headline = $crawler
    ->filterXPath('text > headline')
    ->text()
;
```

Comment: This answers suits perfect to my origin asked question.

Comment: If my answer suits your question and solved your issue ... please accept it. :)

Comment: I tryed it at the moent but the given Example return only a <code> "The current node list is empty."</code> If I use <code> $headline = $crawler
    ->filterXPath('text')
    ->text()
;</code> it returns me a vardump like :<code> string(56) "
     This is the headline
     some boring content bla
"</code>